# Access VBA Form Private Sub calling Public Function in different Module

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In my database I have a public function in a module that receives a SQL string and returns an open recordset. This function works just fine when called by other public subs, both in this module and in other modules.

However if I try to call the same function using the same exact code I get a compile error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."

If I cut and paste the exact code into a different module as a public sub it works normally. I suspect the issue has to do with naming or perhaps hidden variables. I haven't been able to come up with any solutions by searching unfortunately.

```
Public Function Query(SQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim cnnConn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rsRecord As New ADODB.Recordset
   Set cnnConn = CurrentProject.Connection
   rsRecord.ActiveConnection = cnnConn
   rsRecord.Open SQL
   Set Query = rsRecord
End Function

Private Sub Setup()
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim SQL As String
   SQL = "Select * FROM [Configuration]"
   Set rs = Query(SQL) <--- Compile Error
   rs.Close
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you rename the function from `Query` to `fnQuery`, change its return value to `Set fnQuery = rsRecord`, and then change `Setup()` to `Set rs = fnQuery(SQL)` ... does it work?

Comment: Power went out in the office before I could give it a try. I'll test this out Monday. Thank you.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I thought I was in the clear with naming, because it was working from another sub. Hopefully that will teach me to follow proper naming syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch is the problem results from using `Query` as the name of that custom VBA function.

Rename the function from `Query` to `fnQuery` and change its return value to `Set fnQuery = rsRecord`.  Then change the assignment statement in the `Setup()` procedure to `Set rs = fnQuery(SQL)`

Answer (score 1):

I have found using Debug > Compile finds a lot of issues in VBA - it will highlight many errors:

[image]